# Data.frames in R: name autocompletion?

Tags: r, dataframe

Sorry if this is trivial. I am seeing the following behaviour in R:

```
> myDF <- data.frame(Score=5, scoreScaled=1)
> myDF$score ## forgot that the Score variable was capitalized
[1] 1
```

Expected result: returns NULL (even better: throws error).

I have searched for this, but was unable to find any discussion of this behaviour. Is anyone able to provide any references on this, the rationale on why this is done and if there is any way to prevent this? In general I would love a version of R that is a little stricter with its variables, but it seems that will never happen...

Comment: Switch to `[[`, which doesn't do partial matching by default. There is also a `warnPartialMatchDollar` option you can turn on. This is all discussed extensively in `?Extract`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer. Please feel free to repost as answer so I can accept. Will add this option to all my code - this really should be enabled by default.

Comment: Having witnessed debates about this before, I suspect that some members of R Core might respond by saying that exact matching is on by default provided that you use the right function ([[) and that partial matching is quite useful for interactive use so $ should only be used in that context. It can be confusing, though, when the language has aspects that are better/worse for interactive/programmatic uses.

Comment: @joran: Just as a comment, it seems that even maintainers of large packages do not always use the [[ and even use partial matching. Just got these warnings from lme4 after enabling warnPartialMatchDollar. This also means that enabling this option is barely usable, since it will spam your console with warnings from packages.   
Warning in opt$conv : partial match of 'conv' to 'convergence'

Warning in opt$conv : partial match of 'conv' to 'convergence'

Warning in opt$conv : partial match of 'conv' to 'convergence'
Warning in famL$fami : partial match of 'fami' to 'family'

Comment: @RobHall I think it's bad practice for packages to be relying on this, so I'd recommend reaching out to the package maintainers if you come across such issues, [e.g.](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3664)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `$` operator needs only the first unique part of a data frame name to index it. So for example:

```
> d <- data.frame(score=1, scotch=2)
> d$sco
NULL
> d$scor
[1] 1
```

A way of avoiding this behavior is to use the [[]] operator, which will behave like so:

```
> d <- data.frame(score=1, scotch=2)
> d[['scor']]
NULL
> d[['score']]
[1] 1
```

I hope that was helpful.

Cheers!

Comment: An converse note that if you _did_ want `[[` to do partial matching, you could do `d[['score', exact = FALSE]]` (as taken from `?Extract`, h/t @joran)

Answer (score 0):

Using `[,""]` instead of `$` will throw an error in case the name is not found.

```
myDF$score
#[1] 1

myDF[,"score"]
#Error in `[.data.frame`(myDF, , "score") : undefined columns selected
myDF[,"Score"]
#[1] 5

myDF[,"score", drop=TRUE] #More explicit and will also work with tibble::as_tibble
#Error in `[.data.frame`(myDF, , "score", drop = TRUE) : 
#  undefined columns selected
myDF[,"Score", drop=TRUE]
#[1] 5

as.data.frame(myDF)[,"score"] #Will work also with tibble::as_tibble and data.table::as.data.table
#Error in `[.data.frame`(as.data.frame(myDF), , "score") : 
#  undefined columns selected
as.data.frame(myDF)[,"Score"]
#[1] 5

unlist(myDF[,"score"], use.names = FALSE) #Will work also with tibble::as_tibble and data.table::as.data.table
#Error in `[.data.frame`(myDF, , "score") : undefined columns selected
unlist(myDF[,"Score"], use.names = FALSE)
#[1] 5
```