# R data.frame $ operator does fuzzy string matching?

Tags: r, dataframe

Apparently, the `R` `data.frame` `$` operator does fuzzy string matching. Is this a bug?

```
> testdf <- data.frame(letters60 = c("a","b","c"))
> testdf$letters

[1] a b c
Levels: a b c
```

Comment: It doesn't do fuzzy matching. It does partial matching. `testdf$letters5` will return `NULL`. See `?Extract`

Answer (score 0):

The `$` operator needs only the first unique part of a `data.frame` name to index it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32854683/data-frames-in-r-name-autocompletion) a better explanation of the behavior.

An example:

```
testdf$letters60
[1] a b c
Levels: a b c
testdf$letter
[1] a b c
Levels: a b c
testdf$l
[1] a b c
Levels: a b c
```