# How can I disable partial column name matching in an R data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like the following code to error because `df$t` does not exist. I do not want `df$this_is_the_wrong_variable` to be returned:

```
df <- data.frame(
    this_is_the_wrong_variable = c(0, 1),
    r = c(2, 3),
    s = c(4, 5),
    st = c(6, 7), # typo!
)
print(df$t) # this does not give an error!
```

How is this weird concept called, and how can I disable it?

Comment: I marked to close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32854683/data-frames-in-r-name-autocompletion. The `Score`/`scoreScaled`/`score` example in that post is much more instructive than the example I give here - even though the answer given by @GregorThomas here is not given over there (as of now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching the `?options` page for "partial" finds this option:

> `warnPartialMatchDollar:`
>
> logical. If true, warns if partial matching is used for extraction by `$`.

So setting that option (`options(warnPartialMatchDollar = TRUE)`) will turn it into a `warning`.

I don't think there's an easy to to turn only that warning into an error, but looking up a few rows in the `?options` help if you set `options(warn = 2)`, all warnings will be treated as errors.

Alternately, you could use `tibble`s, which don't use partial matching with `$` (though it returns `NULL` will a warning, not an error):

```
library(tibble)
as_tibble(df)$t
# NULL
# Warning message:
# Unknown or uninitialised column: `t`.
```

Comment: Thank you - a warning is helpful enough, I should have specified that in the question.

Comment: It is *crazy* that this is off by default. Are there other warnings one should enable, coming from a programming language that forces developers to write somewhat more sensible code? ;)

Comment: Another example is `df = data.frame(a=1:10); df$a[0]`, which many developers of zero-based languages may write. Using one-based indexing without erroring on obviously incorrect zero-based indexing is a another R design decision I cannot wrap my head around.

Comment: There are a couple adjacent warnings about partial matching of attributes and argument names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[,""]` instead of `$` to *throw an error*:

```
df$t
#[1] 0 1

df[,"t"]
#Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , "t") : undefined columns selected

df[,"this_is_the_wrong_variable"]
#[1] 0 1
```

*Note that `[,""]` relies on `[,,drop=TRUE]`.* To come around this `[,"", drop=TRUE]` could be used. (Thanks to @r2evans pointing this out!)

```
df[,"t", drop=TRUE]
#Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , "t", drop = TRUE) : 
#  undefined columns selected

df[,"this_is_the_wrong_variable", drop=TRUE]
[1] 0 1


tibble::as_tibble(df)[,"t", drop=TRUE]
#Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#✖ Column `t` doesn't exist.
#Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
 
tibble::as_tibble(df)[,"this_is_the_wrong_variable", drop=TRUE]
#[1] 0 1


data.table::as.data.table(df)[,"t", drop=TRUE]
#Error in `[.data.table`(data.table::as.data.table(df), , "t", drop = TRUE) : 
#  column(s) not found: t
 
data.table::as.data.table(df)[,"this_is_the_wrong_variable", drop=TRUE]
#   this_is_the_wrong_variable
#1:                          0
#2:                          1
```

Unfortunately `data.table` still returns a 1-column `data.table`. So `[,""]` with `unlist` could be used:

```
unlist(df[,"t"], use.names = FALSE)
#Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , "t") : undefined columns selected

unlist(df["this_is_the_wrong_variable"], use.names = FALSE)
#[1] 0 1


unlist(tibble::as_tibble(df)[,"t"], use.names = FALSE)
#Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
#✖ Column `t` doesn't exist.
#Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

unlist(tibble::as_tibble(df)[,"this_is_the_wrong_variable"], use.names = FALSE)
#[1] 0 1


unlist(data.table::as.data.table(df)[,"t"], use.names = FALSE)
#Error in `[.data.table`(data.table::as.data.table(df), , "t") : 
#  column(s) not found: t

unlist(data.table::as.data.table(df)[,"this_is_the_wrong_variable"], use.names = FALSE)
#[1] 0 1
```

or `as.data.frame` could be used:

```
as.data.frame(tibble::as_tibble(df))[,"t"]
#Error in `[.data.frame`(as.data.frame(tibble::as_tibble(df)), , "t") : 
#  undefined columns selected
 
as.data.frame(tibble::as_tibble(df))[,"this_is_the_wrong_variable"]
#[1] 0 1
 

as.data.frame(data.table::as.data.table(df))[,"t"]
#Error in `[.data.frame`(as.data.frame(data.table::as.data.table(df)),  : 
#  undefined columns selected

as.data.frame(data.table::as.data.table(df))[,"this_is_the_wrong_variable"]
#[1] 0 1
```

Comment: I actually recommend *against* this method, since it relies heavily on the `[,,drop=TRUE]` default: if `df` were a `tbl_df` or `data.table`, both of them break from inheritance and assume `drop=FALSE`. If one wants exactly one column as a vector without partial matching, then use `[[`: `df[["t"]]` is far clearer and more declarative, and is more robust when possibly dealing with superclasses of `data.frame`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Using `df[["t"]]` will return `NULL` and will not raise an *error*.

Comment: Very good point, that's definitely true. *Edit*: I had recommended explicit `drop=TRUE`, but unfortunately `data.table(a=1)[,"a",drop=TRUE]` still returns a 1-column `data.table`. So much for "superclass" compatibility.

Comment: Thanks again for the comment! Now the solution seems to be somehow robust but I fear that I would not use it. But anyway I learned again something new!